# Pandas: Relationship between a data frame and the numpy.array used to define it

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I just wanted to created two data frames of the same dimensions which where initially empty.  I did it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = np.empty((2, 3))*np.nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(m)
```

But when I changed a particular value in one data frame, all three objects are affected:

```
df2.iloc[1, 2] = 1

print(df2)
    0   1    2
0 NaN NaN  NaN
1 NaN NaN  1.0

print(df1)
    0   1    2
0 NaN NaN  NaN
1 NaN NaN  1.0

print(m)
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  1.]])
```

So it seems that a data frame is just wrapper around an numpy array: no copy is made.  I have not seen this behavior documented anywhere and I just wanted to point it out.  Any comments?

Comment: I don't know about pandas, but for numpy this is the expected behavior. numpy only makes a copy if it must. slicing, transpose, reshape etc create new views of the same data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an **init** arg to DataFrame that let's you specify to copy data from ndarray to the DataFrame.

See source code of pandas [frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py) , line [405](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4cac923706bac52f34cab24b7d5df1d1a0f15cb9/pandas/core/frame.py#L405) and later...
By default, copy is False.

So, you can force copying with something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = np.empty((2, 3))*np.nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m,copy=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(m)

df2.iloc[1, 2] = 1
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Comment: This is great.  I originally modified my code so it would say `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.copy(m))`, but I like your alternative better.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this happens because `df1` and `df2` are pointers to the same memory address. If you're not familiar with pointers, see for example [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Pointers).
A quick way to solve the problem is to copy the shared numpy array in a new array:

```
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = np.empty((2, 3))*np.nan
n = m.copy()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(n)

df2.iloc[1, 2] = 1

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this behavior is that numpy and pandas are designed for efficiency. So the philosophy of developers is:  **contents is  copied only when necessary**.

For example :

```
a=np.ones((2,3))
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df.iloc[0,0]="string" 

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
        0    1    2
0  string  1.0  1.0
1       1  1.0  1.0
```

in this case a copy is made, since dtypes are changed.

Comment: This makes sense to me.